# Laser printer Samsung Xpress M2070W makes smugde on top of paper

Tags: printing, printer, laser-printer

I have Samsung Xpress M2070W for almost a year, toner cartridge was changed only once. Recently it has started making smugde on top of a printed paper (see picture) and small smudges (fat lines) over the paper (they are hard to notice on the scanned picture, but they are definitely there) and the whole paper looks a bit like black powder was spilled on it.

I have already tried to clean printer drum with alcohol and shaking the toner cartridge (usual internet advices), but that didn't help. I am trying to avoid changing the cartridge as this one has still more than half of its capacity.

What could be the possible cause of these smudges? How can I fix that?

Note: Paper on attached scan was printed two times to make smudges more visible, not that it matters.
[Printed paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ad5Te.jpg)

Comment: ring customer support

Comment: From what i have seen there is usually a collector brush, and container for leftover and excess toner, that works off the transfer belt. Transfer belts and this container should be removable, although not as easily as drums. if one could clean the transfer belt and the brush, and empty the container, that might be where it keeps comming from, then you now have to clean all rollers. Otherwise the drum is damaged or not cleaned proper, and  static held toner is falling off the drums too easily and continuing to contaminate rollers and transfer belt.

Comment: The smudges seem to be 6 to 7 cm (2.3" to 2.8") apart so they are caused by a roller that is about 2 cm (0.8") diameter. That is most likely the drum (inside the toner cartridge) but could be the fuser. Have a look at them and check their diameter. Then replace the one that's closest. You can improve your guess by measuring the distance on the paper, as I'm only guessing.